# Merge module manifests in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-build

I have divided my app into a wrapper module and a library module. The library module uses a Service and a Provider. The wrapper and library are in separate projects. I import the library module into wrapper project and build.

I do not want the wrapper to be aware of what is inside the library module. Is it possible to declare the Service and Provider only inside the library manifest and then have the build system merge the two manifests ? My experiments so far indicate the final AndroidManifest does not include the elements from the library module. But I might be missing something. Thanks in advance!